# Incluir todo el código javascript en el fichero js

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

Me han mandado hacer lo siguiente:

Tenemos 2 ficheros, el .html y el .js. En el html incluimos el fichero .js que es donde está todo el código javascript (funciones, variables... Todo el código). Lo que hay que hacer es lo siguiente:

Tenemos esto:

```
<body onload="loQueSea()">
<button onclick="la_funcion()">Botón</button>
...
...
</body>
```

Tenemos también que quitar el "onload=..." y el "onclick=..." del fichero html y ponerlo en el fichero .js

En definitiva, toooooodo lo referente a javascript que esté en el fichero .js.

He estado buscando por internet pero no he encontrado la manera de incluir eso también en el .js y que funcione.

Answer (score 5):

Si **no** usas jQuery, la forma de hacerlo es:

```
document.addEventListener('load',function load() {    
  document.getElementById(<id_boton>).addEventListener('click', function click() {

  });
});
```

También se puede hacer con:

```
document.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById(<id_boton>).onclick=function () {

  };
};
```

pero tiene una pequeña pega: Sólo puedes asignar una función por evento. Si por algún motivo quisieses añadir dos funciones a un elemento para un mismo evento tendrás que usar el primer modo.

Si usas jQuery es más sencillo:

```
$(function () { //equivalente al antiguo $(document).ready(function (){
  $('#id_del_button').click(function clickHandler () {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Para el `onload` existe lo siguiente. Introduce dentro el código que quieras que se ejecute.

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* contenido de loQueSea() */ });
```

Para el `button onclick` simplemente ponle un `#id` y contrólalo con él:

html:

```
<button id="aceptar">Botón</button>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById("aceptar").onclick = function() {la_funcion()};
```

Comment: Estás mezclando jQuery con puro Javascript

Comment: Ojo que en el código de tu respuesta estás asumiendo que se está usando jQuery, que puede no necesariamente ser el caso de esta pregunta.